# Can a generic const call another generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

Consider the following Typescript using generics:

```js
//Assume we've got data coming from somewhere we cannot control the type
const fetchFromSomewhere: (str: any) => any = (str: any) => str

const fetchOne: <T>(str: string) => T = (str: string) => {
    const a = fetchFromSomewhere(str)
    return a
}

//Does not work
const fetchTwo: <T>(str: string) => T = (str: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str) //Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
    return a
}

//Works
function fetchThree<T>(str: string): T {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str) //Can use <T> here
    return a
}
```

`fetchTwo` fails to compile, saying `Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)`. Leaving out the `<T>` results in its return type being `unknown`

`fetchThree` works fine and is a suitable workaround. But is there a way to implement `fetchTwo`, using a const instead of a function?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgXzBN) work for you?  I'm happy to write up how to do this, but please [edit] your example code so as not to have unrelated errors (e.g., either define `doSomethingWith()` or leave it out), so this is a good [mre].

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I've updated my example code. Could you please tell me what `<T,>` is called in Typescript so that I can research it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [annotate the call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) of an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in TypeScript so that it is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), you do so by putting the type parameter declaration immediately before the argument list (and this list must be in parentheses even if there's exactly one of them).  For example, you could turn

```
const idArrow = x => x;
```

into

```
const idArrow = <T>(x: T) => x;
```

which is analogous to the following function statement:

```
function idStatement<T>(x: T) { return x };
```

---

Note that if you are using [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) or your IDE is expecting JSX, the above arrow function might confuse it.  After all, JSX expressions look like HTML tags, and `<T>` looks like that too.  In order to prevent such confusion, you can add a trailing comma after the type parameter (lists of type parameters allow trailing commas):

```
const idArrow = <T,>(x: T) => x;
```

This is completely equivalent to the prior definition of `idArrow`, except that this one will work even if your compiler settings are set to allow JSX.

---

Anyway, that means you can do this:

```
const fetchOkay = <T,>(str: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str)
    return a
}
```

You can't use a `T` parameter inside the body of an arrow function if it's not declared in the call signature:

```
const fetchBad = (str: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str) //Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
    return a
}
```

This latter situation is exactly what was happening in your `fetchTwo`.

---

And note that arrow function expressions are just expressions; they don't have to be assigned to variables.  If you do assign one to a variable, then you can independently choose to [annotate the variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) or not.  That is, you can annotate:

```
const v: Type = init;
```

If you do this, the type annotation for the variable lives entirely on the left side of the assignment operator (`=`), and the initializing expression doesn't get directly involved with that.

In your `fetchTwo` declaration, you were annotating the `fetchTwo` variable with a generic function type:

```
const fetchTwo: <T>(str: string) => T = ...;
```

and your initializing value was the problematic arrow function before, where `T` was not in scope.

```
(str: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str) //Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
    return a
}
```

Hopefully now you can see the disconnect.  Personally I would leave off the type annotation and let the compiler infer the type of the `fetchTwo` variable.  But if you do want to annotate, it means you need to annotate both the variable and the call signature of the function expression, separately:

```
const fetchTwo: <T>(str: string) => T = <T,>(str: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<T>(str)
    return a
}
```

and those really are separate; you could rename function parameters and type parameters in the function expression without having it affect the variable type annotation:

```
const fetchTwo: <T>(str: string) => T = <U,>(xxx: string) => {
    const a = fetchOne<U>(xxx)
    return a
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgEwIICcUgO4wLwwDwAqANAHwAUAHgFwwECUOJMFA3ALABQnAZgK5jAoccPAQBlKAEMoAUwC2MsFELlqtBgG8YKGVF4owzGAF92Xc6Eixuu4AAsAYujliQCjHZk6aZaChqSYACeDNhMgUE4ML5Q-jARoUx+nJyW0DA2UPYA8mAyNCoxcX5wYADmibRRRTQl5ZUanDDNMGmwklGZ9k5uru6eOkV0TS06egbxnMYpHG0ZtnbZANaSkbiEpDUwdRWMMI0cLa3g6R24XYt5hX7Dh6O6+oaSUzNzFwBCkgjVfrWxpbswvsRs05md5llLjJrrEGAB6OEAYUCYBA1lK3zAkgUMAA5ARcQA6KAQMgAJgAzAAGAAstyOY0ekw403MnFKshQ3EkwBktCCAAc+VpJH8UACTKkTrBSnBYLgRTQAERKyUWaUwLC4WVQMxzABuNAIgr52rAcrMMylVgh3VK+XwBHIv22-3qewInQWy1WlvVNouBAwIAKTq2O0qnvWxGdsTFAIaIOONvBF1y0LDNyTjImzxZrw1geDSAANhAQ47Y8U3YCmFH8ABVTYUFvx91Ag5HMFeyHpvAN1Qt+n3cZPKZAA)

Comment: You are correct that even after removing the type annotations, the compiler still inferred the correct types for those functions, resulting in much cleaner code. Thank you.